# Multiple checkbox value in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this form which i submit using ajax and jquery or however it's said..
well, i have this multiple checkbox from which i get some values.

Now i am doing an error here since the values of the checkbox are not being posted in the database..
Here is the html/php part :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['regione'].'" id="regioni_gestite_ag" name="regioni_gestite_ag[]">' . $row['regione'] . '<br>';
}
```

This is how i get it with javascript:

```
var js_regioni_gestite_ag = $('input:checkbox[name=regioni_gestite_ag]:checked').val();
```

This is how i clean it after the form submission:

```
$("#regioni_gestite_ag").prop("checked", false);
```

And finally, the query i use to post it in the database:

```
$postRegioni_gestite_ag = filter_var($_POST["postRegioni_gestite_ag"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$selected_regioni = "";
foreach ($postRegioni_gestite_ag as $postRegioni_gestite_ag) {
$selected_regioni .= $postRegioni_gestite_ag . "/ ";
}
$selected_regioni = substr($selected_regioni, 0, -2);
```

Thanks...

Comment: First of all, you should consider having unique IDs of the checkboxes.

Comment: have you tried showing (e.g. via alert in Javascript or via echo in php) the values you get? how are you actually inserting them into the database?

Comment: I am doing a foreach function to insert them one by one, it works if i just use plan php but with ajax there it makes it difficult..

Comment: The echo won't echo anything, it says undefined, and of course, the error must be in me retrieving the data from the javascript!

Answer (score 0):

The name of your array of checkboxes is `$_POST['regioni_gestite_ag']`, but in your code you are using `$_POST['postRegioni_gestite_ag']` which does not exist.
Try with this line of code instead:

```
$postRegioni_gestite_ag = filter_var($_POST["regioni_gestite_ag"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Suggestions:

- use `print_r($_POST)` to display what your form submits
- remember that all unchecked checkboxes will NOT be submitted and will NOT appear in $_POST. This is the normal behavior, it is not a bug

Comment: Yes but this is how the code works, i mean, the error must be when we retrieve the values, in the js..

Comment: Since your PHP code is not using the correct name for the checkboxes, it will NEVER be able to save the values in the database. Fix your PHP code, try it, and tell us if it works better.

Comment: Well, i tried and as i said it's not this, because i give to the checkbox the name postRegioni_gestite_ag , that's why..